# Add selected class to table row when click on that row

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i have table

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="activity_tab">
    <tr id="list_1">
        <td><span class="new_act">Folder files Created</span>
        </td>
        <td>2013-06-24 02:11 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="list_2">
        <td><span class="new_act">Folder ss Created</span>
        </td>`enter code here`
        <td>2013-06-24 02:11 am</td>
    </tr>
```

and its dynamic table data comes on run time when i click on a row i want to add selected class to that row.
after that i have hyper link at top of page

```
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete">Delete</a></li>
```

this is my hyperlink
now when click on hyperlink the selected row will bhe deleted how can i get the selected row and i have all idea about its deletion 
but could'nt find any solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this -

```
$('.activity_tab tr').on('click',function(){
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
   $('tr.selected').remove();
});
```

Comment: @saqlain786 Are you adding tr's dynamically ?

Comment: @saqlain786 , javascript loop or you loop on your server like a php loop ?

Comment: @saqlain786 then this code should work, demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/YNNVr/1/ ,  and Make sure you are including jQuery.

Comment: dear jquery is included..but its not working really i am confused thanks for cooperation. plz find some solution. :(

Comment: one thing more brother...now on delete click i want to get the id of this selected row or all rows that are selected whose class is selected.. thanks in advance..

Comment: @saqlain786  you can use `this.id` to get the id Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/YNNVr/4/

Answer (score 2):

I would add a class on the selected row. I'm assuming you can only have one selected row at a time, so you'll need to remove any selections when a new row is clicked.

Since your table is dynamic, you'll need to use a delegated event listener to add the selected class. See the documentation of [jQuery's on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more details on delegated events.

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected'); //clear other selections
    $(this).addClass('selected'); //mark this row as selected
});

$('a.delete').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); //stop native link behavior
   $('tr.selected').remove(); //remove selected row
});
```

Note that the listener that adds the `selected` class to a row will affect any `tr` element in the document. If you have other tables on your page, you will need to make the second selector (after the 'click') more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$(function(){
    $(".activity_tab tr").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("red");
    });

    $('.delete').on('click',function(){
       $('tr.red').remove();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YNNVr/

Answer (score 0):

You can add `selected` class to `tr` on click with following code.

```
$('.activity_tab').on('click', 'tr', function(){
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

And if you want to take that one step further, you can use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`, so you can remove the `selected` class with just another click on the `tr`.

You can then select all the `selected` rows and delete them

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(){
   $('activity_tab .selected').remove();
});
```

This removes all rows with `selected` class in the table with `activity_tab` class.